# fb://profile/username does not work in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook

```
NSString *facebookUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.facebook.com/%@", facebookUsername];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", @"fb://profile/", facebookUsername]];
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:url]) {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
} else {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:facebookUrl]];

}
```

This works when opening browser but not opening iOS native app.

In Android, new version of Facebook app requires url like

```
fb://facewebmodal/f?href=http://www.facebook.com/username
```

but in iOS it seems not working like this

Comment: The `username` field is deprecated anyway with Graph API >=v2.0

Answer (score 1):

Here are some schemes the Facebook app uses, there are a ton more on the source link:

Example

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"fb://profile/<id>"];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
```

Schemes

> fb://profile – Open Facebook app to the user’s profile
>
> fb://friends – Open Facebook app to the friends list
>
> fb://notifications – Open Facebook app to the notifications list
>   (NOTE: there appears to be a bug with this URL. The Notifications page
>   opens. However, it’s not possible to navigate to anywhere else in the
>   Facebook app)
>
> fb://feed – Open Facebook app to the News Feed
>
> fb://events – Open Facebook app to the Events page
>
> fb://requests – Open Facebook app to the Requests list
>
> fb://notes – Open Facebook app to the Notes page
>
> fb://albums – Open Facebook app to Photo Albums list

If before opening this url you want to check wether the user fas the facebook app you can do the following (as explained in another answer below):

```
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:nsurl]){
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:nsurl];
}
else {
    //Open the url as usual
}
```

Source

http://wiki.akosma.com/IPhone_URL_Schemes#Facebook

Comment: Please note that these are gathered by trial and error, and are NOT officially supported or documented custom urls for iOS. There's no guarantee that these will work or continue to work in the future.